# set the width of a div to be the same as it's closest sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styling

Is it possible to set the width of a div to be the same as it's closest sibling when the width on that div is `width: auto;`?

In [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crmpicco/6zCt6/) you will see that I have a red, green and blue div. I want the blue div to adjust to the size of the green div (which is dynamic). So if the green div works out to be 200px then I want the blue div to be 200px.

Originally I thought I would be able to put the blue div inside the green one and set `display: inline-block` on the child, but this does not work.

So, if the content of the blue div increases then it won't push the width of the green div out (or the container div). How can this be achieved?

Comment: In your fiddle they have the same width. Where's the problem?

Comment: He mentioned that the green div is dynamic, so if it changes he wants the blue div to change with it.

Comment: @j08691 The problem is that the content of the blue div is pushing the content of the red and green divs past the size they should be. If I enter more lorem ipsum into the blue div the green div will get bigger - I don't want that to be the case.

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>` tag to start...

Comment: What is determining the size of the "green div"? The content inside of it? The simplest solution is to set the width on `.banner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use JavaScript, you can adjust the width whenever the div you want to track changes.  Using jQuery, it's simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Function to sync the sizes of the divs
    function syncSize() {
        $("#banner_description").width($(".banner_secondary_title").outerWidth(true));
    }

    // Sync the size when a change is made
    $(".banner_secondary_title").resize(function(e) {
        syncSize();
    });

    // Initial sync after document setup
    syncSize();
});
```

Here is a fork of your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huaZv/) with this code added, plus I added more text to the secondary title to expand it to show that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Put the blue div inside the green div, add a really high negative `margin-right` (`-999em` or something) to the blue div so that it doesn't stretch its parent green div.

Alternative solution: Put the blue div inside the green div, give the blue div a `position:absolute`. Give the green div a `padding-bottom` matching the height of the blue div. This will only work if the height of the blue div isn't dynamic.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. Can you see it working by modifying my fiddle?

Comment: It should work in theory. Can you first adjust your fiddle so that the problem becomes apparent?